# Google Colab: You are connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilizing the GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

There has been many questions on this topic before, but none of the answers fit my specific question.

I am trying to train Mask RCNN using Keras 2.2.5 on Google Colab. I am getting a message saying "You are connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilizing the GPU". I look up similar questions on stack overflow:

[Why isn't my colab notebook using the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852603/why-isnt-my-colab-notebook-using-the-gpu)

[Anyone experienced the warning about Google colaboratory:You are connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilizing the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360422/anyone-experienced-the-warning-about-google-colaboratoryyou-are-connected-to-a)

but all of them only say to use a package that uses GPU, such as Tensorflow. However, I am using Keras 2.2.5 (presumably with Tensorflow 1.14 backend as I had to install Tensorflow 1.14 for Keras 2.2.5 to work), which is compatible with GPU. Is there any reason why this is happening?

More info:

- Google Colab
- Python 3.6
- I am using Keras 2.2.5 (with Tensorflow 1.14) instead of Keras 2.4.3 because I am using some code from 2017 which works only with Tensorflow 1. Thus, Tensorflow 2 is not possible to use.
- I have used Google Colab to train a GAN before, but this error never appeared. However, I used Tensorflow 2 in that situation.
- I have never needed to add any code to specify that a GPU should be run, and I don't know if I should do that here.
- I had to download Keras 2.2.5 and Tensorflow 1.14 to replace the existing versions (Keras 2.4.3 and Tensorflow 2.2) and I'm unclear if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Can you try importing Keras from TensorFlow 1.14 with `from tensorflow import keras`. Also, are you installing Keras independently of TensorFlow or are you letting TensorFlow automatically install Keras 2.2.5?

Comment: How exactly did you install TensorFlow in colab?

Comment: @Leon Shams I am installing Keras independently of TensorFlow. @Dr.Snoopy I use ```!pip3 install tensorflow==1.14``` and ```!pip3 install keras==2.25``` to install tensorflow and keras.

Comment: Don't install Keras separately just do `!pip install tensorflow==1.14` and import Keras with `from tensorflow import keras`. And you should be using `pip` not `pip3`